# Need to optimize LINQ code using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I 'm new to NHibernate & LINQ. I have a piece of code which I think can be optimized. Please help me to do so.

```
 foreach (var geography in geographyList.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
 {

     var introductionDateDetail = environment.IntroductionDateInfo
                                      .IntroductionDateDetails
                                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationDate)
                                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Geography.Id == geography.Id && 
                                                           x.VaccineDetail.Id == vaccineDetail.Id &&
                                                           x.MasterForecastInfo.Id == masterforecast.Id && 
                                                           x.ViewInfo.Id == viewInfoDetail.ViewInfo.Id);

}
```

The for loop may iterate to about thousand records.And hence the LINQ statement is also executed that many times. Can we write a piece of code where we can execute the LINQ statement just once?

Comment: This looks like case of N+1 query problem. Is there foreign key between Geography and IntroductionDetails and IntroductionDetailsInfo? Then you can use `Fetch` method to eagerly load those introduction details when getting geographies. If not - you can always do one query to get all introduction details where `geographyIds.Contains(x.Geography.Id)`

Comment: No there are no foreign keys between  Geography and IntroductionDetails and IntroductionDetailsInfo. Please can you be more specific on doing one query to get all introduction details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var geographiesId = geographyList.Select(g => g.Id);
var introductionDetails = environment.IntroductionDateInfo
                                  .IntroductionDateDetails
                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationDate)
                                  .FirstOrDefault(x => geographiesId.Contains(x.Geography.Id) && 
                                                       x.VaccineDetail.Id == vaccineDetail.Id &&
                                                       x.MasterForecastInfo.Id == masterforecast.Id && 
                                                       x.ViewInfo.Id == viewInfoDetail
```

Comment: No problem. Starting with ORMs can sometimes be hard and give bad performance, but most of the time it's just understanding what's going on and looking for other way to solve the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Yes exactly. What if I want to eager load the above LINQ query in the question if the entities have foreign key reference?

Comment: Then you can use `Linq to NHibernate`'s Fetch method. Basically you have to declare navigation properties (or whatever it is called in nHibernate) and then you can request fetching related entities (to arbitrary depth). Google it, there must be planty of tutorials out there